# JSON to Dictionary C# .Net 2.0 Standard

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, .net-2.0

I am downloading a JSON in the following format (which I can not change):

```
[
    {"Id":183,"description":"blahblahblah"},
    {"Id":184,"description":"blehblehbleh"},
    {"Id":1000,"description":"and so on..."}
]
```

How can I convert it to became a `Dictionary<string, string>` like so:

```
{
{"blahblahblah", "183"},
{"blehblehbleh", "184"},
{"and so on...", "1000"}
}
```

?

I´m using C# .Net Standard 2.0 (maybe I can use .Net 4.x)

Comment: Typically people use a JSON deserializer for this. I'm most familiar with NewtonSoft, who have an example of what I think you're looking for here:
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest, first convert your json to c# model using [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)

The model for your json looks like

```
public class KeyValue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

then use `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to convert the json to object

```
var results = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValue>>(jsonString);
```

finally use `foreach` to move it to dictionary

```
Dictionary<int, string> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<int, string>();
foreach (var keyvalue in results)
{
     keyValuePairs.Add(keyvalue.description, keyvalue.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Newtonsoft.Json`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json) to deserialize your JSON into a dictionary.

Firstly, make an `Item` class(or whatever other name of class you choose).

```
public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Secondly, deserialize your json using [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm)and assign the key as `Description` and the value as `Id` using [`Enumerable.ToDictionary()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netframework-4.8). Additionally, since your data is a JSON array, you should deserialize to a `IEnumerable<Item>` to get the correct results.

```
var json = "[{ \"Id\":183,\"description\":\"blahblahblah\"},{ \"Id\":184,\"description\":\"blehblehbleh\"},{ \"Id\":1000,\"description\":\"and so on...\"}]";

var deserializedJsonDict = JsonConvert
    .DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Item>>(json)
    .ToDictionary(entry => entry.Description, entry => entry.Id);

foreach (var entry in deserializedJsonDict)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key={entry.Key}, Value={entry.Value}");
}
```

Output keys and values of dictionary:

```
Key=blahblahblah, Value=183
Key=blehblehbleh, Value=184
Key=and so on..., Value=1000
```